# Fire Simulation Not Rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fire

Been working on this fire simulation.  I'm new to the simulation but have done a ton of fiddling around with settings and looked at some questions.  Why is the domain not rendering correctly?  It's rendering as a solid cube (bottom picture) instead of the simulation.  Also, I am in Cycles Render.  Thanks in advance,

Tyler

[image]

[image]

Comment: @JtheNinja, unfortunately not.  Nothing in there helped:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the correct material for the domain. You used a diffuse material for the domain, so it's definitely going to be just another box. The cube on the viewport is just in wireframe draw type, which you can find and change in the object settings.

In Blender Render people used Voxel Data for Smoke Simulations to make the domain transparent and to only show the fire or smoke that you're rendering. But in Cycles there's this Attribute node. Now I have no idea why or how it works, but it works so I'm using it. Here's the node setup I'm using.

[image]

You can change the color of the fire with the color ramp, and you can change the density of the smoke and the amount of light the fire emits by changing the value on the multiply node.

About the Attribute node, you can find more about it here if you wanna see what else you can do with the smoke simulation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/attribute.html

Comment: Hey thanks @Rogue Lotus 4 that was the answer!  It wouldn't let me tag you because I think this is closed but sorry for the late reply.  Was gone all weekend.

Comment: @TylerDahl It's alright. Glad you found your answer. :DD

Comment: Still helpful advice but the link (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/input/attribute.html) not longer works.